# Facebook SDK 3.5 in iOS 5 needs Social.framework

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

Quick question. I'm getting to grips with the FB SDK 3.5 and I was following this tutorial on the Facebook site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

The problem is, it says the SDK needs Social.framework. As far as I'm aware, that's not available on iOS 5. Obviously I can set some frameworks to `optional` but I don't know if that will stop me from posting status updates on iOS 5. Any ideas?

Regards, 
Mike

Comment: It's fine to use the SDK in iOS5, the social.framework is used for the built-in facebook account funtion in iOS6 , on iOS5 , the SDK will skip it

Comment: @adali Perfect, thank you. Would you like to write an official answer so I can give you the rep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine to use the SDK in iOS5, the social.framework is used for the built-in Facebook account function in iOS6, on iOS5, the SDK will skip it.

Comment: Been looking at their sample code and that's exactly what they do.

Answer (score 3):

It's okay to use the Facebook SDK, it needs you to add the `Social.framework` to your project, but this isn't available in iOS 5, not to worry the Facebook SDK will only use it if it's available (for the iOS built in Facebook integration).

But you do need to include it... so you should mark the `Social.framework` as "optional" in the Target's Build phases. This means it won't force it when you compile. Which can make you run into problems for iOS 5 which doesn't have `Social.framework` available.

[image]